# How to extract the custom reverted message inside the transaction object when we're using solidity error keyword?

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethers.js, custom-errors

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

error Unauthorized();

contract VendingMachine {
    address payable owner = payable(msg.sender);

    function withdraw() public {
        if (msg.sender != owner)
            revert Unauthorized();

        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    // ...
}
```

How can I extract `Unauthorized` when the transaction reverts by using `ethersjs`?

Comment: When catch, the error result is roughly as follows: "0x3ccfd60b0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e556e617574686f72697a65642829000000000000000000000000000000000000" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good answer in an article here: https://soliditylang.org/blog/2021/04/21/custom-errors/
and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76550726/how-to-extract-error-message-from-transaction-using-ethers-js